# ¿ cómo hago para obtener mi enlace o link de github pages de mi repositorio?

Tags: android, pandas, lista

Cuando entro en ajustes de mi repositorio y luego voy a la parte de pages no me aparece mi link de github pages de mi repositorio, aunque intenté varias veces, cargué y esperé la página.

Solo en un de mis repositorios pude obtener mi link de la github pagues y esperaba lo mismo de los otros y no fue así.

Comment: Aquí está toda la información https://pages.github.com/